# Sorting multiple conditions with null value

Tags: java, sorting

I have this code, which sorts an array list based on 3 variables

```
        result.sort(Comparator.comparing(FeConsumptionChannelDTO::getMeterName)
                .thenComparing(FeConsumptionChannelDTO::getValueTypeSeq)
                .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(FeConsumptionChannelDTO::getValidFrom).reversed())
        );
```

But the last variable, `getValidFrom` can be null since it is `OffsetDateTime`. If it is null, it throws a NullPointerException. Is there a way to handle null values sorting this way? Or I have to create my own comparing method?

Comment: Change method `getValidFrom()` so that rather than returning null, it returns a `OffsetDateTime`. If you want nulls to be low, then return a minimum value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`nullsFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst(java.util.Comparator)) (`null` < non-`null`) or `nullsLast()` to account for nullability:

```
result.sort(Comparator.comparing(FeConsumptionChannelDTO::getMeterName)
            .thenComparing(FeConsumptionChannelDTO::getValueTypeSeq)
            .thenComparing(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(FeConsumptionChannelDTO::getValidFrom)).reversed())
    );
```